# Automatically generate column value in Spring JdbcTemplate

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, spring-jdbc

I am using Spring 3.2 and want to modify existing calls to database that are using plain JDBC to JdbcTemplate. I'm new to it but I can't find an answer to my question (I hope I post it in correct location).

Assume I have following table in database (some fields ommited):

```
UserRegistration
id int, PRIMARY, autoincrement
reg_year int,
reg_id_in_year int,
reg_number varchar(30),
```

Column "id" is primary key of table and is autoincrementing by 1, starting at 1.

Column "reg_id_in_year" is some kind of logical index. It increments by one, taking the year into account. First UserRegistration in each year will have reg_id_in_year set to 1.

Column "reg_number" is formatted string = 'reg_year / reg_id_in_year'. For example '2017 / 001'.

Example values:

```
id | reg_year | reg_id_in_year | reg_number | 
 1 |     2017 |              1 | 2017 / 001 |
 2 |     2017 |              2 | 2017 / 002 |
 3 |     2018 |              1 | 2018 / 001 |
 4 |     2018 |              2 | 2018 / 002 |
 5 |     2018 |              3 | 2018 / 003 |
```

**Questions**

Is there any functionality in JdbcTemplate that will "automagically" create these values when doing insert of new record (using some custom KeyGenerator maybe)? Now I have to make 2 calls to database:

- First one to get maximum registration number in current year.
- Second one to insert new record.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mention JDBCTemplate that means you use native SQL so I would say it's rather work for SQL. The example is based on named parameters JDBCTemplate but you can adapt it as you wish.

```
INSERT INTO the_table
(reg_year, reg_id_in_year, reg_number)
VALUES
(:year, 
 (SELECT COUNT(*)+1 FROM the_table WHERE reg_year = :year), 
 CONCAT(:year,'/',(SELECT COUNT(*)+1 FROM the_table WHERE reg_year = :year))
)
```

Alternatively you can create a trigger on before insert to calculate the values and fill them

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But what if I would like to get that values back to my Java model after inserting? Do I still need one more call to the database?

Comment: Yes. JDBCTemplate returns only number of rows inserted. Alternatively you can define a stored procedure with IN and OUT params and get the values back from the stored proc